# Can I use "proud" in this phrase: "Proud company for nonprofits"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

This phrase is a title. I am not sure in the use of "proud" before a noun even though I saw in the dictionary that this structure exists. What do you think? How do you understand the phrase?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Most English adjectives are placed before the noun. What led you to believe that "proud" might be different? What did the dictionary mention about the meaning and usage of "proud"?

Comment: *Grammatically*, there's nothing wrong with it. But it sounds awkward to me. Something like "Digital company proudly serving nonprofits" sounds better to me.

Comment: Continuing Accumulation's thought: also, mentioning that a company "proudly" presents [whatever] is really close ot phrasemongering. I would not use it. (Okay, if you are working in advertising, perhaps your customers require you to write such empty phrases.)

Comment: I see nothing wrong with *proud* as an adjective. But I might say "*of* nonprofits" instead. (Depending on the context.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! The phrase with "proud"  seemed me strange as it is not clear why the company is proud. Maybe if it were in the context, I wouldn't pay  attention, but it is a title. I think "company proudly serving nonprofits" is better for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think the phrase is grammatical, but awkward. Are you proud of being a digital company or proud of being a company for nonprofits? I'm not sure of the exact purpose of this title, but I would replace "company" with the products or services that the company is providing, like "Proudly Providing Digital Analytics for Nonprofits"

Answer (score 0):

**proud** [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/proud)

“a **proud** name”

Yes your usage of proud is grammatical.

as in:

*A Proud Digital Company for NON-Profits* , letterhead, etc ...

or

*Proud Digital Company for NON-Profits* , as a company byline, etc ...